# count total orders in the last 30 days from current order date

Tags: sql

I need to create a query that returns count of orders in the last 30 days from the current order date

ex. of the data I have

| user_id | order_id | order_date | previous_order_date | 30_rolling_days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10269 | 247991 | 2019-08-16 | null | 2019-07-17 |
| 10269 | 249971 | 2019-08-18 | 2019-08-16 | 2019-07-19 |
| 10269 | 264301 | 2019-08-30 | 2019-08-18 | 2019-07-31 |
| 10269 | 278619 | 2019-09-10 | 2019-08-30 | 2019-08-11 |
| 10269 | 298092 | 2019-09-24 | 2019-09-10 | 2019-08-25 |

ex. of the result i want to get

| user_id | order_id | order_date | previous_order_date | 30_rolling_days | count_orders_in_the_last_30days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10269 | 247991 | 2019-08-16 | null | 2019-07-17 | 1 |
| 10269 | 249971 | 2019-08-18 | 2019-08-16 | 2019-07-19 | 2 |
| 10269 | 264301 | 2019-08-30 | 2019-08-18 | 2019-07-31 | 3 |
| 10269 | 278619 | 2019-09-10 | 2019-08-30 | 2019-08-11 | 4 |
| 10269 | 298092 | 2019-09-24 | 2019-09-10 | 2019-08-25 | 3 |

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In Standard SQL you would use a window function with a `range` specification:

```
select t.*,
       count(*) over (partition by user_id
                      order by order_date
                      range between interval '-29 day' and interval '0 day'
                     ) as count_orders_in_the_last_30days
from t;
```

Even in databases that support this functionality, the exact syntax might vary.

Another method that is less performant is a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select count(*)
        from t t2
        where t2.user_id = t.user_id and
              t2.order_date <= t.order_date and
              t2.order_date >= t.30_rolling_days
       ) as count_orders_in_the_last_30days
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume your first table is named `orders` and has a column of type *Date* named `order_date` (with *current* order date, compared to `previous_order_date`).

Then this select counts orders, that were ordered within the last 30 days.

```sql
SELECT count(*)
FROM orders
WHERE order_date >= CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL `30 days ago`
```

Not what the value in column `30_rolling_days` means.